# DRIVER_OBJECT.DriverSection

Tags: windows, struct, driver, wdk

Does anyone have an idea what is the structure of the DriverSection pointer in the x64 bit version of win7. In 32 bit I used the following:

```
typedef struct _KLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY {
   LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderLinks;
   PVOID ExceptionTable;
   ULONG ExceptionTableSize;
   //ULONG padding1;
   PVOID GpValue;
   PVOID NonPagedDebugInfo;
   PVOID DllBase;
   PVOID EntryPoint;
   ULONG SizeOfImage;
   UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;
   UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;
   ULONG Flags;
   USHORT LoadCount;
   USHORT __Unused5;
   PVOID SectionPointer;
   ULONG CheckSum;
   //ULONG Padding2;
   PVOID LoadedImports;
   PVOID PatchInformation;
} KLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, *PKLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY;
```

And everything was working but on x64 it is crashing when trying to dereference the LIST_ENTRY. Any pointers/tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> And everything was working but on x64 it is crashing when trying to dereference the LIST_ENTRY. Any pointers/tips would be greatly appreciated

If you can hook up a kernel debugger, you can verify whether or not the DriverSection object matches your definition. To do this, pick a driver you wish to debug - I tend to use a simple one I have. Load its symbols by fixing the symbol path to include its pdb, then break into windbg or kd and type:

```
.reload
```

To reload the symbols. Then you can load the driver with:

```
sc start drivername
```

having created its service assuming it is a legacy driver. Type:

```
bu drivername!DriverEntry
```

to set a breakpoint on the DriverEntry for this module. The difference between `bp` and `bu` is that `bu` breakpoints are evaluated and set on module load. Currently, of course, `DriverEntry` won't be called, but if we reload the driver it will:

```
sc stop drivername
sc start drivername
```

Now your breakpoint should be hit and rcx will contain the `DRIVER_OBJECT` structure, since it is a pointer argument and pointer/integer arguments are passed in rcx,rdx,r8,r9 according to the Windows ABI. So, you can print out the driver object structure with:

```
dt _DRIVER_OBJECT (address of rcx)
```

Which will give you a pointer to the driver section. Then, type:

```
dt _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY (driver section object pointer)
```

This should give you your driver section object. `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` is actually present in the Windows symbols, so this will work.

Using the debugger, you should be able to dereference the `LIST_ENTRY` pointers (`.flink` and `.blink`) successfully (try `dpps` on the address of the _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`structure, for example). If you do it successfully, one of those addresses will resolve to`nt!PsLoadedModuleList`.

---

What I'm trying to say is that in a roundabout way, is that:

1. Either there is a bug in your code somewhere, or
2. You've hit upon a synchronisation issue. Remember, this structure is supposed to be opaque and we're not supposed to be modifying it in any way. It's also liable to change on us, and we don't know where the lock for synchronising access to it is.

If you are certain 1 is not the case, it is likely 2 is. Luckily, Microsoft actually provided a function to get the information from these structures called [`AuxKlibQueryModuleInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You do need to add an extra library to your driver, but that's not the end of the world. Include `Aux_klib.h`. There's also a code sample on the MSDN page showing how to use it - it's pretty straightforward.